# Aggregate function doesn't want to respect months in quarters

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm dealing with the problem following. I want to convert monthly data to quarterly. The way I want to have it is a function which first output is data and second one is 1,2 or 3. If I choose certain number it should pick proper month as a quarterly date. So we have 12 months, 3 in each quarter. I divided it into four groups :

1- January(Q1), April(Q2), July(Q3), October(Q4)

2- February(Q1), May(Q2), August(Q3), November(Q4)

3- March(Q1), June(Q2), September(Q3), December(Q4)

If I pick 1 I want to pick January for the first quarter, April for the second quarter and so on...

If I pick 2 I want to have February for the first quarter, May for the second quarter and so on...

If I pick 3 I want to have March for the first quarter, June for the second quarter and so on...

I have a code following :

```
date3<-(seq(as.Date('2000-11-01'),as.Date('2020-06-01'),by = '1 month'))
x<-rnorm(length(date3))
y<-runif(length(date3))
z<-rexp(length(date3))
df3<-data.frame(date3,x,y,z)
    agg_quarter<-function(data,method){
        aggregate(data[-1], list(yq = as.yearqtr(data$date)), function(x) x[method])}
    agg_quarter(df3,1)
    agg_quarter(df3,2)
    agg_quarter(df3,3)
```

The problem with this code is that, it doesn't recognize witch month we are dealing with. I mean we are starting from November so for  `agg_quarter(df3,1)` I should have `NA`, for `agg_quarter(df3,2)` and `agg_quarter(df3,3)` it should pick respectively November and December as the value of fourth quarter.
But with the code following `agg_quarter(df3,1)` picks November as the value for the last quarter, `agg_quarter(df3,2)` chooses December and `agg_quarter(df3,3)` takes `NA`. Do you have any idea how it can be solved ? I thought that aggregate can automatically check what month in quarter we are exactly looking for.

Comment: If the question is how to find the year/month of the ith month  (i = 1, 2, or 3) of the quarter that a given date lies is in then `as.yearmon(as.yearqtr(date)) + (i-1)/12`

Comment: Are you sure about that ? I see months all month doubled

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Don't know what you did but this gives `Aug 2020`: `i <- 2; date = Sys.Date(); as.yearmon(as.yearqtr(date)) + (i-1)/12`

Comment: And this gives the ith month (i = 1, 2, or 3) of the quarter instead of the quarter itself: `aggregate(df3[-1], list(ym = as.yearmon(as.yearqtr(df3[[1]]))+(i-1)/12), mean)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column with month number of the quarter, then extract the data where `method` and the month number matches.

```
library(dplyr)

agg_quarter<-function(data,method){
  data %>%
    mutate(month = lubridate::month(date3) %% 3, 
           month = replace(month, month == 0, 3)) %>%
    group_by(yq = zoo::as.yearqtr(date3)) %>%
    summarise(across(x:z, ~.x[month == method][1]))
}
agg_quarter(df3,1)

#     yq        x      y        z
#  <yearqtr>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 2000 Q4      NA     NA     NA      
# 2 2001 Q1   -0.340  0.534  0.567  
# 3 2001 Q2    1.38   0.865  0.517  
# 4 2001 Q3   -0.145  0.238  0.297  
# 5 2001 Q4   -1.02   0.208  0.539  
# 6 2002 Q1    0.603  0.926  0.0333 
# 7 2002 Q2    0.178  0.638  1.92   
# 8 2002 Q3    0.106  0.395  0.00905
# 9 2002 Q4    0.862  0.986  0.388  
#10 2003 Q1   -0.601  0.805  1.78   
# … with 69 more rows
```